# How to change a variable eveytime a page is rendered

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the following codes to generate 2 time stamps for a mongoose query in a NodeJS route.

```
const endtime = new Date().toISOString();
const endtimehour = new Date(endtime);
x = endtimehour.getUTCHours();
const endtimemin = new Date(endtime);
y = endtimemin.getUTCMinutes();
starttime = endtime;
if (x === 0 && y < 30) {

    starttime = new Date(Date.now() - 86400000);
    starttime.setUTCHours(0, 30, 0, 0);
    console.log(starttime.toISOString());

} else {
    starttime = new Date();
    starttime.setUTCHours(0, 30, 0, 0);
    console.log(starttime.toISOString());

}
```

purpose of the code above is to calculate 2 variables starttime and endtime.
Now I am trying to use these variables in a query below

```
router.get('/users', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) =>
Users.find({"when": {"$gte": starttime, "$lt": endtime}}).exec()
.then(data =>{    
  console.log(endtime);
  console.log(starttime);
  });

})
);
```

For the first time it calculates the variables perfectly but on refresh, it keeps on using the same values. How can I ensure that it picks the fresh value each time page is rendered or refreshed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put that calculation code outside of the controller so it only runs one time. You have to put that logic inside the controller or just wrap it around a function and calls from inside the controller. Something like this:

```
const getTimes = () => {
   // put your logic of time calculation here
   return { starttime, endtime };
}

router.get('/users', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) =>
    const { starttime, endtime } = getTimes();
    Users.find({"when": {"$gte": starttime, "$lt": endtime}}).exec()
      .then(data =>{    
           console.log(endtime);
           console.log(starttime);
   });
}));
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try to run the server after making this change

const { starttime, endtime } = getTimes();
^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
       
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...